# when adding navigation drawer to the application. this does not work

Tags: android

Since a few days ago I decided to program for Android and buy a book about that. There are several examples and I have achieved them satisfactorily but at the moment of programming the navigation drawer and running it on my cell phone it appears that it closed unfortunately. In the console of Android Studio does not appear any error and I was reviewing codes, example, etc and I have not been able to solve the problem.

Here you can see part of the application code to create and initialize the toolbar and the drawer layout

```
        package com.example.luisenrique.clase_aplicacion;

        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
        import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
        import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.example.luisenrique.clase_aplicacion.fragments.DetalleFragment;
        import com.example.luisenrique.clase_aplicacion.fragments.SelectorFragment;

        import static android.R.id.toggle;
        import static com.example.luisenrique.clase_aplicacion.R.id.appBarLayout;
        import static com.example.luisenrique.clase_aplicacion.R.id.drawer_layout;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
            private AdaptadorLibrosFiltro adaptador;
            private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
            private TabLayout tabs;
            private DrawerLayout drawer;
            private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                if((findViewById(R.id.contenedor_pequeno)!=null) && (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contenedor_pequeno)==null)){
                    SelectorFragment primerFragment=new SelectorFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.contenedor_pequeno,primerFragment).commit();
                }
                adaptador=((Aplicacion)getApplicationContext()).getAdaptador();
                appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
                //Pestañas
                TabLayout tabs=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Todos"));
                tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Nuevos"));
                tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Leidos"));
                tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
                tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
                        switch (tab.getPosition()){
                            case 0: //Todos
                                adaptador.setNovedad(false);
                                adaptador.setLeido(false);
                                break;
                            case 1: //Nuevos
                                adaptador.setNovedad(true);
                                adaptador.setLeido(false);
                                break;
                            case 2: //Leidos
                                adaptador.setNovedad(false);
                                adaptador.setLeido(true);
                                break;
                        }
                        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}
                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}
                });
                Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();
                NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){
                int id=item.getItemId();
                if(id==R.id.nav_todos){
                    adaptador.setGenero("");
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(id==R.id.nav_epico){
                    adaptador.setGenero(Libro.G_EPICO);
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(id==R.id.nav_XIX){
                    adaptador.setGenero(Libro.G_S_XIX);
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(id==R.id.nav_suspense){
                    adaptador.setGenero(Libro.G_SUSPENSE);
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return  true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed(){
                DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                else{
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
        <!--activity main.xml-->
```

the main activity is where the main view will be shown and it will be linked to app_bar_main_xml where the other components are located that have no relation to the navigation drawer and work correctly and therefore I will not put the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <!--El contenido de la actividad-->
            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <!--El contenido del navigation drawer-->
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <!--nav header-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Audiolibros"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="http://www.androidcurso.com"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--menu activity_main_drawer.xml-->
```

in the menu you will see how the navigation drawer will be sectioned. what items will be available and how they will be grouped.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_todos"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Todos los generos"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_epico"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Poema épico"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_XIX"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Literatura siglo XIX"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_suspense"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Suspense"/>
    </group>
        <item android:title="Acciones adicionales">
            <menu>
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_preferencias"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                    android:title="Preferencias"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_compartir"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Compartir"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </menu>
```

It is to call the texts that are required in other classes, there are only two that are called opening and closing.

```
    <!--Strings-->
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Clase_Aplicacion</string>
        <string name="drawer_open">navigation drawer abierto</string>
        <string name="drawer_close">navigation drawer cerrado</string>
    </resources>
```